# What does getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentElement} mean?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd

I have a popup which moves when scrolled. When I searched for a solution to it, I found the below code

```
getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentElement}
```

I understood that whenever an event like collapse or expanded is trigger this gets called but does it mean?
I am not able to understand it completely other than that that it will stay fixed in its position when popup is displayed.

Comment: `getPopupContainer` expects a  callback as value. `trigger => trigger.parentElement` is a short for `(trigger) => trigger.parentElement` which itself is a short for `function(trigger) { return trigger.parentElement }`

Comment: @Rajesh so that would mean we are returning the parent of the expanded popup so that it stays in the parents position only and not move on scroll?

Comment: I guess so. With what we see here, All i can say is, you are passing reference of parent element as value for `getPopupContainer`